# How to import renderings/components from solution folder to sitecore

Tags: presentation, training-certification

I copied over the **views** and **controllers** from the solution folder to my local project, built and deployed. sitecore got updated with new files.

I am wondering how to import the **renderings/components** from the solution folder to sitecore. I see a lot of ***.yml** files such as **one-column.yml**. Can I import those to sitecore?

I tried copying them into my local project and syncing with sitecore but they don't show up as changes.

Comment: Can you go to site.com/unicorn.aspx and hit Sync All?

Comment: Make sure to also have unicorn configured correctly by checking the setting value <sc.variable name="sourceFolder", you can take a look at the example https://sitecorediaries.org/2020/08/22/how-to-setup-unicorn-for-helix-based-sitecore-project/